# Updating values that are packed inside a uint256

Tags: solidity, uint256, bit-manipulation

I recently learned about packing smaller uints inside bigger uints. for example:
uint64, uint64, uint8, uint120 all packed into a single uint256. my question is, how can i update one of the values inside with out unpacking and repacking and without affecting any of the other values?

heres my packing and unpacking functions:

```
    function packExample() public pure returns (uint packed) {
        uint value1 = 1; //[0-63] -- uint64
        uint value2 = 2; //[64-127] -- uint64
        uint value3 = 3; //[128-135] -- unit8
        uint value4 = 4; //[136-256] -- uint120

        packed = value1;
        packed |= value2 << 64;
        packed |= value3 << 128;
        packed |= value4 << 136;


    }

    function unPackExample(uint packed) public pure returns (uint value1, uint value2, uint value3, uint value4) {
        value1 = uint(uint64(packed));
        value2 = uint(uint64(packed >> 64));
        value3 = uint(uint8(packed >> 128));
        value4 = uint(uint120(packed >> 136));
    }
```

if I wanted to update value3 for example, what would that function look like? also if theres a better way to pack and unpacked please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To make this a bit easier to visualize, let's say you have four numbers and each takes 2 bits. 8 bits in total.

Your 8 bit integer might look for example like this: 10 10 11 01. In decimal, the numbers are: 2 2 3 1, so 2231.

Let's say you want to decrease the second *2* to *1*. You take *1* and multiply it by *10^2=100* which results in *100*. Then you simply calculate 2231 - 100 = 2131.

Of course you need to adjust this (add range checks, etc), but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: thanks! I think i kind of get it, but I'm not sure how to implement that in solidity.

Comment: That's just multiplication, addition and exponentiation. Basic math.

Comment: gotcha, for my project ive opted to unpack to a struct, update, then repack and store. makes more sense for my application